# How to add more layers to existing model (eg. teachable machine application model)?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras-layer, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I'm trying to use the google model from teachable machine application https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/ by adding few more layers before output layers.
When I retrain the model, always return this error:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_25 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 5 but received input with shape [20, 512]

Here's my approach:

[image]

When retrain the model it return error:

[image]

If I retrain the model without adding new layers, it's working fine.
Can anybody advise what was the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

if you want to add layers in between two layers for a pre-trained model, it is not as straightforward as adding layers using add method. if done so will result in un-expected behavior

analysis of error:

if you compile the model like below(like you specified):

```
model.layers[-1].add(Dense(512, activation ="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(5))
```

output of model summary :

```
Model: "sequential_12"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
sequential_9 (Sequential)    (None, 1280)              410208    
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_11 (Sequential)   (None, 512)               131672    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 128)               768       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 32)                4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 165       
=================================================================
Total params: 546,941
Trainable params: 532,861
Non-trainable params: 14,080
_________________________________________________________________
```

everything looks good here, but on closer look :

```
for l in model.layers:
  print("layer : ", l.name, ", expects input  of shape : ",l.input_shape)
```

output :

```
layer :  sequential_9 , expects input  of shape :  (None, 224, 224, 3)
layer :  sequential_11 , expects input  of shape :  (None, 1280)
layer :  dense_12 , expects input  of shape :  (None, 5) <-- **PROBLEM**
layer :  dense_13 , expects input  of shape :  (None, 128)
layer :  dense_14 , expects input  of shape :  (None, 32)
```

**PROBLEM** here is that dense_12 expects an input of shape(None, 5) but it should expect input shape of (None, 512) since we have added Dense(512) to sequential_11, possible reason would be adding layers like above specified might not update few attributes such as output shape of sequential_11, so during forward pass there is as miss-match between output of sequential_11 and input of layer dense_12(in your case dense_25)

**possible work around would be :**

for your question "adding layers in between sequential_9 and sequential_11", you can add as many layers as you want in between sequential_9 and sequential_11, but always make sure that output shape of last added layer should match input shape expected by sequential_11. in this case it is 1280.

code :

```
sequential_1 = model.layers[0] # re-using pre-trained model
sequential_2 = model.layers[1]

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp_sequential_1 = Input(sequential_1.layers[0].input_shape[1:])
out_sequential_1 = sequential_1(inp_sequential_1)

#adding layers in between sequential_9 and sequential_11
out_intermediate = Dense(512, activation="relu")(out_sequential_1)
out_intermediate = Dense(128, activation ="relu")(out_intermediate)
out_intermediate = Dense(32, activation ="relu")(out_intermediate)

# always make sure to include a layer with output shape matching input shape of sequential 11, in this case 1280
out_intermediate = Dense(1280, activation ="relu")(out_intermediate)

output = sequential_2(out_intermediate) # output of intermediate layers are given to sequential_11 

final_model = Model(inputs=inp_sequential_1, outputs=output)
```

output of model summary:

```
Model: "functional_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_9 (Sequential)    (None, 1280)              410208    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 512)               655872    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 128)               65664     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 32)                4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1280)              42240     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_11 (Sequential)   (None, 5)                 128600    
=================================================================
Total params: 1,306,712
Trainable params: 1,292,632
Non-trainable params: 14,080
```

Comment: thank you for your time. I did follow your advise, unfortunately, it returned another error.

Comment: It returned another error:


----> 4 input = Input(model.layers[0].input_shape[0])



296                      'to Input, not both at the same time.')
    297   if batch_input_shape is None and shape is None and tensor is None:
--> 298     raise ValueError('Please provide to Input either a `shape`'
    299                      ' or a `tensor` argument. Note that '
    300                      '`shape` does not include the batch '

ValueError: Please provide to Input either a `shape` or a `tensor` argument. Note that `shape` does not include the batch dimension.

Comment: oh, i forgot. layer.input_shape returns first axis as None which represents variable batch size. not including that will fix the error.

Comment: It works but it ruins the original model architecture.
Let's go back to the original model above, is it possible to add some layers in between  sequential_9 and sequential_11 without ruin its architecture?

You can get the model from the github link below:
https://github.com/seansothey/Research_Project/blob/main/google_model.h5

Comment: Awesome!!! It works, really appreciate for your time. One more question, the reason to add dense layer 1280 before output later, is to followed the original architecture because the sequential_11 is expected to connected with 1280 units. Am I right?

Comment: yes, you are right. this is because you specified not to change model architecture, it is mandatory have layer that has output shape matching input shape of sequential_11.